# How to convert file input stream to blob data type without using byte array

Tags: jpa, groovy, spring-data-jpa, blob, hibernate-mapping

I am trying to write a code to store a zip file as Blob data in the database using Spring data/JPA (coding in groovy). I am able to store the file easily using a byte array as entity,

```
@column(Name = "zipFile")    
byte [] zipFile
```

But what i need is the below

```
@column(Name = "zipFile")    
Blob zipFile
```

i need to find a way to convert my fileinputstream to Blob data type.

```
Blob image = Hibernate.getLobCreator(session).createBlob(bFile);
```

Aware of the above method.But the code is in my service layer so not sure how can i implement session here.
Please let me know if there is a better method to convert a filestream to Blob data type, i need to somehow get rid of Byte array.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11926487/how-to-stream-data-to-database-blob-using-hibernate-no-in-memory-storing-in-byt?rq=1

Comment: (Be aware that such an innocent field might cause a large overhead and slow things down. Then place it in a second entity for instance.) I still would use `@Lob` byte[] zipFile;` - http://www.codejava.net/frameworks/hibernate/hibernate-binary-data-and-blob-mapping-example

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to stream data to database BLOB using Hibernate (no in-memory storing in byte\[\])](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11926487/how-to-stream-data-to-database-blob-using-hibernate-no-in-memory-storing-in-byt)

Comment: @IvanPronin, like i said they all seem to be using session and usage of session in service layer is not normally recommended and thats why i am asking for a better approach.