# Hibernate, transactions and data size

Tags: spring, oracle, hibernate, jpa, transactions

I am currently using jpa/Hibernate and Oracle in my project.
I have a service demarcated with transaction boundaries. 
In this boundary I have a insert/update of blob which can be max size of 200 mb.
Considering data size do transaction have any limit?
With this data any impact exceptions or degradation is possible?
Couple of factors I checked is transaction timeouts and Oracle  packet sizes (tdu and sdu).
Any pointers is much appreciated!

Comment: @G Shenoy Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11926487/how-to-stream-data-to-database-blob-using-hibernate-no-in-memory-storing-in-byt) helps you

Comment: Yes this is helpful definitely. Let me double check with transaction semantics.